# Couldn't find the toolbar items in my xcode 7 IDE

Tags: xcode7

I couldn't see the sceme button or Run button and any toolbar icons in my xcode 7.0.

Please let me know how to view that. its very difficult to me for understanding the scheme name and simulator type running without knowing the build.

Comment: may be your toolbar is hidden you have to unhide it from view > show Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the top bar and select “Icon and text”

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me.  I tried right clicking on the top bar as suggested above, but only saw a menu that read, "Hide Toolbar".  Once I did that, I clicked on the top bar again and saw the menu with "Icon and Text" as a choice.  Unfortunately, that did nothing.

I closed the project and opened it back up again.  The top bar was set back to normal with the run and stop buttons, the scheme pulldown menu, etc.